# Why is my variable out of scope in org-roam-capture?

Tags: org-capture, org-roam, scope

I would like to define an function using `org-roam`'s capture system. However, I want to create a new function, not use the variable `org-roam-capture-templates` and the related function `org-roam-capture`.

I want to create a function that takes a string as an argument so that I can use it in the captured text. In this case, I want to be able to specificy a string (e.g. "TODO", "DONE", or other states) that is added to the beginning of the captured item.

This is my attempt so far:

```
(defun org-roam-capture-inbox-test (item-string)
    (interactive)
    (org-roam-capture- :node (org-roam-node-create)
                       :templates '(("i" "inbox" plain "* %(eval item-string) %?"
                                     :if-new (file "Inbox.org")))))
```

Evaluating this function creates this capture item: `* %![Error: (void-variable item-string)]`. Unless I'm mistaken, this means that `item-string` is out of scope when it is called in `org-roam-capture-`.

Why is `item-string` out of scope in this case? How can I pass it to `org-roam-capture-`?

Comment: What happens if you add a second argument `t` to the `eval` call? i.e. make it `... %(eval item-string t) ...`.

Comment: When I add `t` to the `eval` call, I get the same capture: `* %![Error: (void-variable item-string)]`.

Comment: @NickD No, Nick. The `(eval item-string)` is within a string. So you would you have to replace the quoted list by something like `(("i" "inbox" plain ,(format "* %%(eval %s) %%?" item-string) :if-new (file "Inbox.org")). Note the backquote instead of the quote!

Comment: Yes, I know - the thing is that `org-capture` will parse the `%(eval ...)` form eventually and it will evaluate it. But the evaluation environment will be far removed from the definition environment: I was wondering if there would be any connection. If the OP is right, there does not seem to be any - so, yes, it's just another backquoting problem.

Comment: Using the backquote and `(("i" "inbox" plain ,(format "* %s %%?" item-string) :if-new (file "Inbox.org")))` as the template fixed the problem. Note that I needed to remove the `eval` from the solution. If @Tobias wants the reputation for the solution, you can write it up and I'll mark it as correct. Otherwise, I'll write up and post your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tobias suggested, this is partially a [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) problem. This is the solution:

```
(defun org-roam-capture-inbox-test (item-string)
    (interactive)
    (org-roam-capture- :node (org-roam-node-create)
                       :templates `(("i" "inbox" plain ,(format "* %s %%?" item-string) :if-new (file "Inbox.org")))))
```